# the element 'transport' cannot contain child element 'extendedProtectionPolicy' because the parent element's content model is empty

Tags: visual-studio-2008, windows-7, iis-6

I inherited a web application that makes calls to a web service. It is being developed in VS2008 SP1 and deployed to IIS6 (2k3 Server R2).

Since I upgraded to Windows 7 Enterprise RTM, the following line gets added to my Web.config:

```
<extendedProtectionPolicy policyEnforcement="Never" />
```

The problem is that when I deploy this application to my web server I get the following error:

The element 'transport' cannot contain child element 'extendedProtectionPolicy' because the parent element's content model is empty

I can remove the line and it will work, but its a pain and I forget sometimes to remove it again (VS2008 adds seems to add it back whenever I load the solution!!).

Is there anything that can be done?

Here is my 'transport' section:

```
<transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None" realm="">
        <extendedProtectionPolicy policyEnforcement="Never" />
</transport>
```

Thanks
Neil

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So far, I have found that if you comment out that section... it seems to prevent Visual Studio from adding it back again.

Comment: Which section?  The <transport> or the <extendedProtectionPolicy>?