# Using Exchange EWS... Can't figure out how to access the dll?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, exchange-server, exchangewebservices

I've downloaded and installed from here...

http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=13480

As suggested here..

[Getting started with Exchange Web Services 2010](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2471303/getting-started-with-exchange-web-services-2010/2505239#2505239)

I try to create a new project in Visual Studio and do this...

`using Microsoft.Exchange.Webservices` but `Exchange` is not defined.

I've tried finding it in the **Add Reference...** dialog with no luck...

Comment: In the Add Reference dialog, you might need to navigate to the installation folder of the EWS libraries.  Things aren't always listed in the main list [(annoying, I know)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1987691/assembly-installed-into-the-gac-not-showing-up-in-visual-studio)

Comment: is there something that's suppose to tell me where they are installed? the installer just runs... if it's just unpacking the dll why does it need to "install"....

Comment: Other libraries do this too (like Rhino Mocks, in my linked question).  I feel your pain.  Check in your Program Files folders for it, and check the GAC.  As noted, not everything in the GAC is listed in Visual Studio.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can find `Microsoft.Exchange.Webservices.dll` (Version 1.2) in the program files path.

`%ProgramFiles%\Microsoft\Exchange\Web Services\1.2\`

Answer (score 1):

It is a NuGet package now.  I had the NuGet package as a reference, but I was still getting the yellow warning symbol on the reference.

[image]

I just had to right click my project, select **Manage NuGet Packages...**
Then I uninstalled and reinstalled the same version.  Shrug.

If you don't have the NuGet package, search for **Microsoft.Exchange** in the manager.