# Silverlight project will only work with Silverlight assemblies

Tags: silverlight, sharepoint-2010, exchange-server-2010

Now a days, I make one application in Silverlight to get Emails from MS Exchange Server online. So first i create Silverlight Application in Visual Studio 2010. Now Issue is that when i add reference Microsoft.Exchange.Webservice.dll to silverlight application so error shown below:
"You cant add a reference to Microsoft.Exchange.Webservice.dll as it was not built against the Silverlight runtime. Silverlight project will only work with Silverlight assemblies".
I have searched error but failed to solve this issue.. please help me..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Silverlight uses a different runtime and a subset of the regular .Net framework, which is why you can only reference other SIlverlight libraries.

I would also think you shouldn't be referencing the Microsoft.Exchange.Webservice.dll directly anyway, rather you should be adding a web service reference to a web service exposed by an existing installation of Exchange, and then using webservice calls to retrieve the emails.

### Edit:

This excellent previous StackOverflow should be enough to get you underway: *[Getting started with Exchange Web Services 2010](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2505239/109702)*

Comment: +1 Was just about to post the same answer.  Ravi, silverlight isn't designed to solve this kind of problem.  FYI: When microsoft think it is something silverlight should do, then they provide a silverlight version of the assembly.

Comment: hi slugster, thanx for reply..
But i have using online exchange server so How i can use its webservice?

Comment: @Ravi, check my edit, it is an excellent answer which has also been expanded with helpful references by the question asker.

Comment: hi slugster, I have been already used this is for Sharepoint application but in sharepoint i reference dll and use class name like "ExchangeService" for getting Emails.. But using webservice i cant found any code for getting inbox mails..