# services wsdl exchange web services

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, exchangewebservices

Where do I get exchange services.wsdl? I have googled around and I am not able to find anything to download.
I am trying to develop an application to insert data into outlook on exchange server. I currently i have it done to work on a localhost/desktop, and i am trying to change my code to use webservices.

```
using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook;
    using OutLook = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook;
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MAPIFolder CustomFolder = null;
    OutLook._Application outlookObj = new OutLook.Application();
    OutLook.MAPIFolder fldContacts = (OutLook.MAPIFolder)outlookObj.Session.GetDefaultFolder(OutLook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderContacts);
    CustomFolder = contactsFolder.Folders.Add("MyNewAddressBook", Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderContacts);
```

So I am trying to change the above by using exchange, however, i am not sure where to get the reference! do I need to inquire from my network admin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using C# / .NET then your best bet is going to be to use Exchange Web Services. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2471303/getting-started-with-exchange-web-services-2010?rq=1) has a way to get started on EWS.